# Re-Routing Query String in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

I have a website that has many URLs that look like this:

```
https://www.website.com/view?id=56
https://www.website.com/category?name=music
```

Which I would like to look like this:

```
https://www.website.com/view/56
https://www.website.com/category/music
```

This website is deep into development and it is too late to switch to a framework that makes this simpler.

My question is: What is the simplest way to do this (again, without using Klien or Composer, or any other framework-type things)? Perhaps something in .htaccess or something along those lines.

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable mod_rewrite in your apache config and rewrite what you want with some rules.

Try this ones:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9-]+)/?$ view?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ category?name=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. The page is loading but without any CSS or PHP (just the plain html)

Comment: Could you post your css url?

Comment: Sorry but it's not online yet because it is still being developed. I'll keep trying different things

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. It was looking for files inside a folder called /view/ which doesn't exist. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's ok. I don't ask for the css code, just wanted to see the url it is not loading after the rewrite rules

Comment: Yes, it seems to be fine. Thank you!!